Snowflake SQL repeat results
I would like to repeat results based on a result field output. So what ever the value in the field result is the data in data in name, type and amt should repeat that many times.
So I get the below result output
enter image description here
This is want I want to get
enter image description here

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/generator

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/values

WITH Data AS (
    SELECT 'Bob' AS NAME, 'Human' AS TYPE, 60 AS AMT, 5 AS Entry
)
SELECT NAME, TYPE, AMT
FROM Data
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS num UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5
) AS Numbers
WHERE Numbers.num <= Data.Entry;

